# Onbackpressed redirect to particular fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

In my app i have navigation drawer,So i have one MainActivity and rest are fragments. My app is working fine. Whenever i press back button it redirect to previous fragment.it works fine.but what i want is after successful payment i am displaying Successful payment page,on this page when user press back button i want to redirect to HomeFragment,but right now it goes to Placeorder fragment.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

Comment: when payment is successful, remove all other fragment, display the SuccessfulPayment page, then remove it after few seconds

Comment: how to do that??

Comment: try out this replace your if condition with if(!activeFragment.onBackPressed())  , i think it will work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override your `onBackPress` method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragment != null && fragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
    fragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }else {
    super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simulate function as below in abstract class fragment

```
    /**
     * Handle "Back" key pressed.
     * @return TRUE if the "Back" key pressed was handled. FALSE indicate it's not handled and parent class can handle it.
     */
    public abstract boolean onBackPressed()
```

And in MainActivity, you will handle this function

```
     @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mSelectedFragment != null && mSelectedFragment.onBackPressed()) {
            return;
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is mSelectedFragment

Comment: fragment is in visible state, can integrate with user interface

Comment: where can i call this method

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFeedFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Don't do this:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Comment: simply call that home fragment but don't use addToBackStack

Comment: but where can i call this

Comment: Actualy the back button should not have to take user anywhere on back press keep usere there only and add button and take user to homeFragment

Answer (score 0):

One way would be saving previous fragment (`previousFragment`) variable while opening new fragment and making it null when you are in first or placeholder fragment .... then check value of `previousFragment` inside `onBackPressed` method , if null perform exit operation else replace fragment with `previousFragment` by which you will get back to previous fragment on back press.

Comment: i dont want to go previous fragment..only for payment successful

Answer (score 0):

inside your `onBackPressed()` do like this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(getSupportFragmentManger.findFragmentByTag("paymentFragment") != null){
          //add homeFragment;
        }  
        else{
            if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
            else {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set some global variable (true when payment is success else false) in Application class and in onbackpressed of your activity just check that variable is true or not.Then in backpressed of your activity call this function.

```
  public void clearBackStack() {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
            manager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this simple method
declare an integer as

```
 public int count;
```

initialise this count as `count=0` in your main page

now include this in your main activity

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (count == 1) {
        if (exit) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            exit = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }else {
        toolbar.setTitle("Home");
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        count=1;
        display(0);
    }
}
```